# Logarithm product inequality - Where is the Mistake?

Tags: inequality, logarithms

## Question

Solve the inequality

$$\log_{0.5}(2^x-1)\cdot\log_{0.5}\left(2^{x-1}-\frac12\right)\le 2$$

### My Working

Let

$$t=\log_{0.5}(2^x-1)$$

We have that

\begin{align}
\log_{0.5}(2^x-1)\cdot\log_{0.5}\left(2^{x-1}-\frac12\right)&\le 2\\
\log_{0.5}(2^x-1)\cdot\log_{0.5}\left(\frac{2^x-1}{2}\right)&\le 2\\
\log_{0.5}(2^x-1)\cdot\left[\log_{0.5}(2^x-1)-\log_{0.5}\left(\frac12\right)\right]&\le 2\\
\log_{0.5}(2^x-1)\cdot\left[\log_{0.5}(2^x-1)-1\right]&\le 2\\
t\cdot(t-1)&\le 2\\
t^2-t-2&\le0\\
(t-2)(t+1)&\le0\\
-1\le t&\le 2
\end{align}

I substituted the value of $t$ back, but there is a problem. For example, I did this for the left part of the inequality:

\begin{align}
\log_{0.5}(2^x-1)&\ge -1\\
0.5^{\log_{0.5}(2^x-1)}&\ge 0.5^{-1}\quad (\text{Mistake?!})\\
2^x-1&\ge2\\
2^x&\ge3\\
x&\ge \log_2 3
\end{align}

For some reason, I think the second line (of the above) is wrong, as the rest seems fine. Could anyone please tell me why I got this wrong and what the correct answer is? Thank you!

Comment: Would it be helpful to use $\log_2 u = -\log_{0.5} u$?

Comment: @BrianTung so does that second step not work if the base of the log is less than 1 but larger than 0

Comment: No, I just thought it might be easier to avoid errors.

Comment: @BrianTung thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The incorrect line is:
$$
\log_{0.5}(2^x-1)\cdot\left[\log_{0.5}(2^x-1)-\log_{0.5}\left(\frac12\right)\right]\le 2
$$
This should be:
$$
\log_{0.5}(2^x-1)\cdot\left[\log_{0.5}(2^x-1)+\log_{0.5}\left(\frac12\right)\right]\le 2
$$
Or equivalently, you could write:
$$
\log_{0.5}(2^x-1)\cdot\left[\log_{0.5}(2^x-1)-\log_{0.5}\left(2\right)\right]\le 2
$$
This gives you:
$$
(t+2)(t-1)\le 0
$$
$$
-2\le t\le 1
$$
Which gives us two conditions:
$$0< x\le \log_25$$
and
$$x\ge \log_2\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)$$
with a final answer of:
$$\log_2\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\le x\le \log_25$$

Comment: +1, very clear explanation